# Using CUDA with nvidia optimus in Intel mode (14.04)

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, nvidia-optimus, cuda

I'm using a Thinkpad T430 with a NVS 5400M and an integrated Intel HD card.

Since it's not possible to use cuda-gdb when the nvidia card is used for video output, I tried to use CUDA while in Intel mode. But unfortunately I get the following error message:

```
no CUDA-capable device is detected in ...
```

Using google I found an old [guide](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/295.59/README/optimus.html) for using nvidia CUDA with optimus cards. But when I try to load the driver manually I just get another error message:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_331': No such device
```

Is there a way to use CUDA and thus the cuda-gdb while in Intel mode?

fyi: everything but the cuda-gdb works fine when I'm on nvidia mode.

Comment: How did you install the driver exactly?